# Explicando la sintaxis en "no es mucho provoque"

Tags: sintaxis, abreviaturas

Según adiviné,  "*no es mucho provoque*" significa "no falta mucho más para que provocase", por exemplo en la siguinte cita de *Cuestiones de Mística* del p. Gonzalez Arintero (nota 1 p. 83) :

"Mas querer con pasos de bestias llegar a este monte de luz obscura y de obscuridad lucida, no es mucho provoque el enojo de Dios".

Este tipo de sintaxis "abreviada" me parece un poco extraña. ¿Os gramáticos españoles han escrito algunas explicaciones a mas sobre esto?

Comment: Parece español antiguo. No es correcto en el español contemporáneo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**Mas querer con pasos de bestias llegar a este monte de luz obscura y de obscuridad lucida, no es mucho provoque el enojo de Dios**".

Interpretación

"**Mas querer con pasos de bestias llegar a este monte de luz obscura y de obscuridad lucida, es motivo suficiente para que provoque el enojo de Dios**".

Por intentar buscar atajos y no querer decidirse a entrar por la puerta estrecha de la abnegación cristiana ni abrazar cada cual su propia cruz para poder seguir a Cristo por su angosto camino, ya sea por desidia o falta de perseverancia a la hora de pedir a Dios su Espíritu, es esta búsqueda de atajos para llegar a la Contemplación de Dios, motivo o conducta suficiente para que provoque el enfado de Dios.

[image]

**QUIETISTAS** y **QUIETISMO**

El Quietismo o Molinosismo (por el P. Molinos) fue un nombre peyorativo que se le dio a un movimiento místico surgido en el siglo XVII en el seno de la Iglesia católica. Las ideas generales propuestas por el sacerdote y místico español Miguel de Molinos (**a quien se debe el nombre de Quietismo**) fueron condenadas como heréticas por el Papa Inocencio XI en 1687.

El Padre Molinos enseñaba **la pasividad** en la vida espiritual y mística, ensalzando las virtudes de **la vida contemplativa**. Sostenía que el estado de perfección únicamente podía alcanzarse a través de la abolición de la voluntad: *es más probable que Dios hable al alma individual cuando ésta se encuentra en un estado de absoluta quietud, sin razonar ni ejercitar cualquiera de sus facultades, siendo su única función aceptar de un modo pasivo lo que Dios esté dispuesto a conceder*.

Por otro lado, ya durante el siglo XVI Santa Teresa no cesaba de lamentarse de la escasez de buenos directores que, *conociendo las vías del espíritu, fueran capaces de enseñarlas, alentar y no estorbar en el aprovechamiento, y de la abundancia de aquellos que en todo lo espiritual ponen miedos y no ven más que peligros, mientras no quieren verlos en el camino ancho*. También San Juan de la Cruz, cuyos libros fueron objeto de duras críticas, dice que son innumerables los que por ignorancia apartan a la gente de la contemplación a la que Dios invita, y la obligan a resistir a la acción delicada del Espíritu Santo.

El concepto del Quietismos y de la Contemplación espiritual provoco la desconfianza de todas las Ordenes Religiosas y Escuelas de pensamiento hacia la "Mística", desconfianza que aumento y se generalizo casi en todas partes. Los divulgadores de estas desconfianzas estaban preocupados por los excesos del Quietismo y la Contemplación.

En el S. XVIII los recelos en contra de la Contemplación son tan generales que incluso se llega a evitar el término.

Más tarde, ya en el S. XIX y XX, el P. González Arintero contribuyó con sus escritos a la restauración de los "Estudios Místicos", difundiendo muchas de las ideas sobre Mística, Santidad y Perfección, y que posteriormente influirían en el Concilio Vaticano II

De ahí que en estos escritos del P. González Arintero por procurar renovar el "Quietismo", se intente reflejar en general los lamentos de tantos creyentes por verse tan olvidados, abandonados y despreciados en los caminos del Espíritu y en contra de la "Oración Contemplativa" por aquellas mismas personas que justamente deberían recomendarla.

**P.D.** "Mas querer con pasos de bestias llegar a este monte de luz obscura y de obscuridad lucida, **no es mucho** provoque el enojo de Dios". Lo que no es mucho, es poco. "Mas querer con pasos de bestias llegar a este monte de luz obscura y de obscuridad lucida, como poco provoque el enojo de Dios". La sintaxis es correcta, aunque muy poco utilizada, ya que la oración esta inserta en estructuras del S. XIX y principios del XX.

Comment: Gracias. Si entendí correctamente, trata-se de un caso de omisión das preposiciones "para que", y la forma más completa seria "no es mucho para que provoque"

Comment: Gracias a ti! Otra forma de entenderlo "Irse por los atajos, es suficiente para que provoque el enfado de Dios", "Ir por caminos más cortos, es razón para que provoque el enfado de Dios", "Buscar una senda más corta para hallar la contemplación o gracia de Dios, es aguantar mucho, es bastante, para provocar el enfado de Dios". Ejem. Cuando se dice " No le falta razón en enfadarse" significa que "Tiene mucha razón en enfadarse".